# Creating feedback reduction filter in AudioKit

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, audiokit, feedback

So I've moved forward with an audio processing app. It's basic purpose is to allow a user to use the microphone input and headphone output to produce a balanced audio signal for practical audio work. I've managed to produce a balanced signal, but now I would like to also make sure that, if I'm outputting this signal to external speakers, the sound doesn't feed back into the phone. I've read in apple's documentation that you can set the microphone's preferred polar pattern, but I don't know how effective that will be, and I'm not sure if it will work with AudioKit. If possible, I would like to make a filter that can identify when there's feedback in the sound and reduce the offending frequencies.

If anyone knows of a simple way to accomplish this using audiokit, or any sites that explain audio effect algorithms, please comment.